# Spring unitTest on DAO class using jdbc JAVA

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jdbc

I am trying to make a unit test on a method from a DAO class. Dao class is using JDBC. I am trying to unit test it but without using test data base. I must test it using some data structure for storing all the information.

```
public class UserProfilesDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSourceAccessor msa;

        public long getUserServiceId(long userId, int serviceId) {
            String sql = msa.getMessage("sql.select.service_user_id");
            Object[] params = new Object[] { userId, serviceId };
            int[] types = new int[] { Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER };
            return getJdbcTemplate().queryForLong(sql, params, types);
        }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Did you heard of mock or doubles/stub?

Comment: @SMA  yes know about Mocking but till now i was writing tests without using data base. That is why i ask here for some example.

Comment: @Raja Anbazhagan the question is that i am asking form some help how to make this unit test because after this i have bigger methods to test and i want to have some example,

Answer (score 1):

getJdbcTemplate() appears to be a method that you want to mock out.

In your unit test, declare a UserProfilesDao member as follows:

```
@Spy
private UserProfilesDao classToTest;
```

the @Spy is a mockito annotation.

in your unit test declare a setup method as follows:

```
@Before
public void preTestSetup()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doReturn(what ever you want).when(classToTest).queryForLong(
        any(xxx.class),
        any(yyy.class),
        any(zzz.class));
}
```

where xxx, yyy, and zzz are the queryForLong parameter types.

Comment: Thank you :) In doReturn(...) what i have to write. Is is correct to return an user by id ?

Comment: Is there a reason for spying the DAO instead of mocking it?

Comment: you spy because it is the class you are actually testing.  Why would you mock the class you are attempting to test?  That seems counterproductive

Comment: in the doReturn, return the value that you want to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in DTO Objects and maintain DTOs in a Map with proper keys.
For test, retrieve data from map using key according to your need!